# Resolve method call in annotation processor

Tags: java, java-8, annotation-processing

I want to write an Annotation Processor to check that a Method is called only in specific places. For example:

```
interface Command {
    @MustOnlyBeCalledByWorker
    void execute();
}

class Worker {
    void work(Command cmd) {
        cmd.execute(); // This is ok for the annotation processor
    }
}
class Hacker {
    void work(Command cmd) {
        cmd.execute(); // annotation processor gives an error
    }
}
```

I already have an annotation processor with `@SupportedAnnotationTypes("*")` that uses the Compiler Tree API to get all `MethodInvocationTree`s.

I thought that from there, I could get the Declaration of the called method.

Now I can easily get the method name and the argument expressions.

But say I also want to distinguish between overloaded `execute()` methods with the same number of arguments.
Do I need to handle the whole overload resolution myself? I think this would also mean to manually resolve the static types of all arguments, and in some cases even the type arguments of other methods.

So here is my Question: How can I get the correct declaration of a potentially overloaded method? Maybe I can somehow get it out of a `JavacTask`?

I am using the IntelliJ IDEA 14 and Oracle's Java 8 compiler. For now Support for Language Level 7 would be sufficient, but a solution with Java 8 Support is preferred.

Comment: AspectJ can work with the control flow, maybe that might help you somehow.

Comment: Ok so i found out that with the AbstractTypeProcessor, I can get the called method using `final ExecutableElement calledMethod = utils.getCalledMethod(SmartTreePath.getPath(getCurrentPath(), node));`.

I did not try that before because the only hints I found were that this class has been both added and removed again in Java 7. Now I use the implementation from here: [https://github.com/reprogrammer/checker-framework/blob/master/javacutil/src/org/checkerframework/javacutil/AbstractTypeProcessor.java]
I am not really sure if doing it this way is officially supported, but for now this works.